# How can I choose one of three data input pipelines in the graph runtime in the Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, graph

I build three data input pipelines when I construct the graph.

```
images_pipe_1 = input_images('list1')
images_pipe_2 = input_images('list2')
images_pipe_3 = input_images('list3')
```

I want to choose one of them in the graph runtime according to the global_step like this:

```
if global_step < 2000:
  data input pipeline = images_pipe_1
if global_step >= 2000 and global_step < 5000
  data input pipeline = images_pipe_2
if global_step >= 5000
  data input pipeline = images_pipe_3
```

But in the tensorflow, there variables like global_step are tensors, they should be operated by tf functions, not by python.
I have tried to use tf.cond, but it only can solve the problem of two options.

```
images_pipe = tf.cond(tf.greater(global_step, tf.constant(2000, tf.int64)), lambda:images_pipe_2, lambda:images_pipe_1)
```

In this situation, there are three options. I do not know how I can solve it. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by tf.case

```
pipeline = tf.case({tf.greater(global_step, tf.constant(5000,tf.int64)):images-pipe_3, tf.less(global_step, tf.constant(2000,tf.int64):images_pipe_1)}, default=images_pipe_2, exclusive=True)
```